# Programatically setting (remote) master address for launching Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Note that the following ***local*** setting *does* work:

```scala
sc = new SparkContext("local[8]", testName)
```

But setting the ***remote*** master programmatically does not work:

```scala
sc = new SparkContext(master, testName)
```

or (same end result)

```scala
val sconf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(testName)
    .setMaster(master)
sc = new SparkContext(sconf)
```

In both of the latter cases the result is:

```sh
[16:25:33,427][INFO ][AppClient$ClientActor] Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077/user/Master...
[16:25:33,439][WARN ][ReliableDeliverySupervisor] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077] 
has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

The following command line approach for setting the spark master consistently *works* (verified on multiple projects):

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://mellyrn.local:7077 
   --class $1 $curdir/sparkclass.jar )
```

Clearly there is some additional configuration happening related to the command line `spark-submit`.  Anyone want to posit what that might be?

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX shell script below:

SP_MAST_URL=`$CASSANDRA_HOME/dse client-tool spark master-address`
echo $SP_MAST_URL

This will print the master from your Spark cluster environment. You may try this command utility provided by Spark and pass it on to SPARK SUBMIT command.

**Note**: CASSANDRA_HOME is the path where Apache cassandra installation is done. It could be any UNIX FILE path depending upon each environment.